# Workflow does not work correctly

Tags: 7, workflows

I create a workflow for the content type "Article":

```
creation -> draft
draft -> expert review
expert review -> head review
head review -> publish
```

When authors create an article node, and send it for "expert review," they can still view and edit the node but "expert review" cannot view the node.

Is there any bug or trick for Workflow?

Comment: I found out its incompatible with Organic Group

Comment: The question is too generic, to be answered in its actual form; you don't report the other settings you changed. It's not clear to me what you mean with _"expert review" cannot view the node_. Did you create an "expert review" role?

Comment: author, expert and head are roles, and "creation -> draft -> expert review -> head review -> publish" is workflow states

Comment: all thing I should know about workflow was here: http://drupal.org/node/270000

Comment: If it's a workflow state, then saying that _"expert review" cannot view the node_ doesn't make sense; users with specific roles can view (or not view) nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your Workflow again (after you created the states) and scroll down to the bottom to 'Access control' section. In there you can set permissions for each state.

You can also look at the [Workflow Fields module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow_fields) if you want to set access to individual CCK fields.